# Refining HTML Agility Pack Nodes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, fizzler

I am using HTML Agility Pack and Fizzler (So I can use CSS selectors) to scrape a results page.

I start by creating html document and then creating a list of nodes so each node is an individual result.

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> sections = document.DocumentNode.QuerySelectorAll("selector");
```

I now want to drill down into each of these nodes to grab the specific data I want but I am getting lost here.

I tried:

```
foreach (HtmlNode n in sections)
{
    var phone = n.QuerySelectorAll("selector");

    string myVar = phone.InnerHtml; // this doesn't work, the innerhtml property is not there.
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to approach this?  All of the examples I have seen stop at creating the nodes list.

Answer (score 0):

OK it was stupidly simple.  I needed to use `QuerySelector` instead of `QuerySelectorAll`